# How to convert xml to excel using mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

> Input  we will get input from email,ftp etc as xml file
>   required output: excel file

Comment: Is something specific in your attempt that's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

- The lovely new Mule Datamapper (mule 3.4) will process the xml to Excel, you can select and transform the required attributes.
- The older approach is to process the xml and convert to csv files that can be read by most excel tools. The xml can be eaily parsed to maps  and requred part output using **Maps to CSV** connector with the flatpack formatting file.